# panic: reflect: call of reflect.Value.FieldByName on interface Value

Tags: go, reflection, reflect

I have a variable of type `interface{}` and I want to change the value of a field using reflection. How can I do it? Variable must be of type `interface{}` due to other requirements. If the variable isn't of type `interface{}` all works, otherwise code throws

```
reflect: call of reflect.Value.FieldByName on interface Value
```

my code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    a := struct {
        Name string
    }{}

    // works
    reflect.ValueOf(&a).Elem().FieldByName("Name").SetString("Hello")
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", a)

    var b interface{}
    b = struct {
        Name string
    }{}
    // panics
    reflect.ValueOf(&b).Elem().FieldByName("Name").SetString("Hello")
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", b)
}
```

Answer (score 11):

The application must call `Elem()` twice to get the struct value:

```
reflect.ValueOf(&b).Elem().Elem().FieldByName("Name").SetString("Hello")
```

The first call `Elem()` dereferences the pointer to `interface{}`.  The second call to `Elem()` gets the value contained in the interface.

With this change, the panic is `reflect.Value.SetString using unaddressable value`.

The application cannot set fields directly on the struct value contained in the interface because values contained in an interface are not addressable.

Copy the struct value to a temporary variable, set the field in the temporary variable and copy the temporary variable back to the interface.

```
var b interface{}
b = struct {
    Name string
}{}

// v is the interface{}
v := reflect.ValueOf(&b).Elem()

// Allocate a temporary variable with type of the struct.
//    v.Elem() is the vale contained in the interface.
tmp := reflect.New(v.Elem().Type()).Elem()

// Copy the struct value contained in interface to
// the temporary variable.
tmp.Set(v.Elem())

// Set the field.
tmp.FieldByName("Name").SetString("Hello")

// Set the interface to the modified struct value.
v.Set(tmp)

fmt.Printf("%#v\n", b)
```

[Run it on the Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/R84relUPWng).

Answer (score 1):

The interface `b` is initialized using the value of the anonymous struct, so `b` contains a copy of the struct, and the values are not addressable. Initialize `b` using a pointer:

```
var b interface{}
    b = &struct {
        Name string
    }{}
    reflect.ValueOf(b).Elem().FieldByName("Name").SetString("Hello")
```

Comment: I need solution for both `b = &struct{}` and `b = struct{}`. Any idea how can I achieve it?

Comment: > The interface b is initialized using the value of the anonymous struct
anonymous struct it's only example, it doesn't work for normal struct as well

Comment: You cannot set the value of a member of a struct if you have a pointer to a copy of that struct. That is what the varisble b is. See what happens if you did ValoeOf(a) in your first case.